# Fill class vector while Separating behavior from data

Tags: c++

I wanted to create a class where I can separate the behavior from data. The objective is to fill a vector without having to use the setter function.

I create a function called `X()` to push elements into the vector. The problem is that the size of the vector is always `0` `a.X().size() = 0`.

I am a little lost and i can't find another way to do it. Other than using a setter function. Is there another way to doing that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class A {
    public: 
     A() {};
     std::vector<int> X() {return x;}
    private :
     std::vector<int> x;

};

int main()
{
  A a;
  a.X().push_back(10);

  std::cout << a.X().size() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to return the vector by reference like so: `std::vector<int>& X() {return x;}`

Comment: _I wanted to create a class where I can separate the behavior from data._ Hmmm. IMHO, OOP means _not_ to separate data from behavior.

Comment: REFERENCE Yessssss that's itttt. Stupid me. sheesh. Thank you @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: If you make `X` return a reference, then it's no better than making `x` public in the first place. If you want to separate behavior and data, then at least make a function taking the value to be added to the vector as an argument.

Comment: This abstraction is exactly as leaky as the one you are trying to avoid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there goes my encapsulation down the drain then. 

Thank you are a lot for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function `std::vector<int> X() {return x;}` returns copy of vector inside your class, so when you're calling `a.X().push_back(10);` you're adding item to copy, which doesn't affect vector inside your object. To solve this, you've got to return your vector by reference, like this:

`std::vector<int>& X() {return x;}`

**Edit:** As was mentioned in comments to your question, it's not good practice
to return non-`const` references to your class private members.

Better approach here is to create separate method for adding new items
into your vector by passing them as arguments. Example:

`void addItem(int item){ x.push_back(item); }`